# Ionic 2: Reorder items from Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently creating an Ionic notes app where I will allow the user to rearrange the items in the list with the reorderArray() function. However, I am using Firebase so I get this error on this.notesList.

> Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable'.

I am not sure how to use this with Firebase so anything would help. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="editmode">
  <ion-list reorder="true" (ionItemReoder)="reorderItem($event)">

    <ion-item *ngFor="let note of notesList | async">
      <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="addToTrash(note.id)"></ion-checkbox>

      <ion-label>
        <h1>{{ note.name }}</h1>
        <span>{{ note.note_date | date: 'shortDate' }}</span>
        <span>{{ note.text }}</span>
        <span>{{ (notesList | async)?.length }}</span>
      </ion-label>

    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
export class NotesPage {

  notesList: Observable<any>;
  editmode: boolean = false;
  trash = [];

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public database: AngularFireDatabase,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
    this.loadNotes();
  }

  loadNotes() {
    const loader = this.loadingCtrl.create();
    loader.present().then( () => {
      this.notesList = this.database.list('/notes').valueChanges();
      loader.dismiss();
    })
  }

  reorderItem( indexes ) {
    this.notesList = reorderArray(this.notesList, indexes);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.notesList` is an *Observable* in your case. `reorderItems` can only order *array-likes*. so something like this should do the trick.

```
notesList: any[];

[...]

loadNotes() {
  const loader = this.loadingCtrl.create();

  Observable.fromPromise(loader.present()).switchMap(() => { //1
    return this.database.list('/notes').valueChanges(); //2
  }).subscribe((list) => { //3
    this.notesList = list; //4
    loader.dismiss();
  });
}

reorderItem( indexes ) {
  this.notesList = reorderArray(this.notesList, indexes);
}
```

1. execute promise `loader.present` "the rxjs way"
2. switch to the second Observable. `.valueChanges()` returns an Observable.
3. subscribe to second Observable to get the streamd value
4. write the value to this.notesList to trigger UI-Bindings

**Edit**

`<span>{{ (notesList | async)?.length }}</span>`
has to be 
`<span>{{ notesList?.length }}</span>`
because `notesList` is not async (anymore).

There are (at least) two ways of displaying values that are streamed through observable pipes. One is the async pipe in the template and one is the way i explained. The async pipe subscribes to the observable under the hood and returns the value. But with the pipe you can't reorder the items that easy.

Comment: This is great thank you. However, I got a Runtime Error that says InvalidPipeArguement: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'